# Masonry / Isotope Jquery Plugin Filter

Tags: jquery, filtering, jquery-isotope

Evening All

I am having an issue with the isotope jquery plugin  - filtering.

I have created a sample page here

http://www.csr500.co.uk/websites/v9/preview.html

Now my issue is when I filter using the buttons in the top right of the page, then the filtering works, however I would like the non selected items / elements to fade out and the page to then sort itself out, ie the selected items to reorder themselves, currently they simply jump into place, which I dont like.

Having done some research it appears as though it is something to do with .masonry('reload') however I am not able to work out where to place this code.

My isotope code is located right at the bottom of the page.

Thanking everyone in advance, I am sure its me being a bit dim.

Cheers

Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those CSS rules to your stylesheet file:

```
.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
     -moz-transition-property: height, width;
      -ms-transition-property: height, width;
       -o-transition-property: height, width;
          transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
       -o-transition-property:      -o-transform, opacity;
          transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}

/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0s;
          transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

For more info read here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was me being a bit dim